# How to change Parent component's state from Child component if it's rendering with map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a problem - i need to change parent component's state from child component. I tried standard variant with props, but it's not helping in my case.

Here is code of Parent component:

```
class ThemesBlock extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        currentThemeId: 0
    }
}

changeState(n){
    this.setState({currentThemeId: n})
}

render() {
    let { data } = this.props;

    return (
        data.map(function (item) {
            return <Theme key={item.id} data={item} changeState= 
{item.changeState}/>
        })
    )
 }
}
```

And here is my code for Child Component:

```
class Theme extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.changeState = this.props.changeState.bind(this);
}

render() {
    const { id, themename } = this.props.data;
    const link = '#themespeakers' + id;

    return (
        <li><a href={link} onClick={() => this.changeState(id)} 
 className="theme">{themename}</a></li>
    )
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary issue is that `changeState` should be bound to the `ThemesBlock` instance, not to the `Theme` instance (by `ThemesBlock`).

Here's an example where I've bound it in the `ThemesBlock` constructor (I've also updated it to show what theme ID is selected):

```js
class ThemesBlock extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            currentThemeId: 0
        }
        this.changeState = this.changeState.bind(this);
    }

    changeState(n) {
        this.setState({currentThemeId: n})
    }

    render() {
        let { data } = this.props;

        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                Current theme ID: {this.state.currentThemeId}
                </div>
                {data.map(item => {
                    return <Theme key={item.id} data={item} changeState={this.changeState} />
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class Theme extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.changeState = this.props.changeState.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        const {
            data: {
                id,
                themename
            },
            changeState
        } = this.props;
        const link = '#themespeakers' + id;

        return (
            <li><a href={link} onClick={() => changeState(id)} className="theme">{themename}</a></li>
        )
    }
}


const data = [
    {id: 1, themename: "One"},
    {id: 2, themename: "Two"},
    {id: 3, themename: "Three"}
];
ReactDOM.render(
  <ThemesBlock data={data} />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to move map() before return? Like this:

```
render() {
    let { data } = this.props;

    const outputTheme = data.map(function (item) {
        return <Theme key={item.id} data={item} changeState= {item.changeState}/>
    })

    return (
        {outputTheme}
    )
 }
```